# Selenium webdriverwait: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

gives the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 21, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, timex).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by, element))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have not used `__init__()` why is this error there?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_path=r"C:\Users\Bhanwar\Desktop\New folder (2)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://priceraja.com/mobile/pricelist/samsung-mobile-price-list-in-india")
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)
i=0
timex = 5
by = By.ID
hook = "product-itmes-"  # The id of one item, they seems to be this plus 
                         # the number item that they are
button = '.loadmore'
while i<3:
    element_number = 25*i
    element=hook+str(element_number)# It looks like there are 25 items added each time, and starts at 25
    WebDriverWait(driver, timex).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by, element))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(button).click()
    time.sleep(5)  # Makes the page wait for the element to change
    i+=1
```

Comment: Please don't enter tracebacks by hand or re-format them. I suspect the actual error may say `__init__()` instead of `init()`, for example.

Comment: need solution for this

Comment: Then make sure you are **accurate** in your reporting. This *is* caused by the `__init__` method; that's the method called when creating an instance. `presence_of_element_located()` is a class with a `__init__` method, and it only takes one `locator`, not two arguments.

Comment: True, you haven't used `init()`, but the classes you call, do. make sure you are not passing more arguments than needed on line 21.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`presence_of_element_located()` only takes one argument, a locator, which is a tuple. You forgot to add the `(...)` parentheses needed for a tuple in a call:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timex).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((by, element)))
#          these make this a tuple ^ and       ^
```

Comment: Are we supposed to be answering questions with typographical errors or closing them?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: not sure if this is a typographical question. Feel free to vote to close it if you think it is.

Comment: I did, according to some people in  http://socvr.org/, we are just supposed to close and not answer so they can be deleted easier. You are a mod so that is why I asked.

Comment: I had to do a bit of reading before I realised *what* object was throwing that exception and why, then some more as to how selenium locations work. So it wasn't an obvious typo to me until I learned how you are supposed to pass in a location to Selenium objects.